# Fresh install for MacBook

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, hard-drive

I have a 2012 MacBook Pro. A1278. It’s getting very very slow. Boot up is 5 mins. Random freezing. I thought it was just old. But I’ve done research and apparently it’s either the hard drive failing or hdd cable so I’m gonna replace both. SSD is gonna be faster anyways.

Question is: do I need to do anything to do a brand new install when ssd is in as I haven’t got a disc or usb install for OS X? I don’t want to clone or anything as all my important stuff is in cloud.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do when you want a fresh install is to follow these steps on here:

[How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)

and then boot from it (press and hold ⌥-Option while powering up) to install the OS.

<s>Other then the above proceddure this formats the drive **completly** so I recommend to do a backup before even though you have everything in the cloud.</s> Sorry, nevermind since you add a new SSD.

After finishing the installation keep in mind to [enable TRIM](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/29/use-trimforce-trim-ssd-mac-os-x/) since you installed a 3rd-party SSD!
Then you can copy all your needed files.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a very good page for this and I would only repeat.

In your case the best choice is to use Shift-Option-⌘-R when turn on your Mac

The mac will download the latest version of the installation "cd" and start it. (if the last installed version is 10.13.2, it will download 10.13.6 and not 10.14.6 or 10.15.1) You format the disk, install OS and it's done.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904

Comment: Awesome thank you. I’ll try that out.

Comment: @AaronCornwell While using macOS Recovery (as The33Coder suggests) is easier, needlol's suggestion will leave you with a thumb drive with an installer, which could be useful in the future if you have to reinstall macOS again, and your wifi is spotty or absent.